# django bootstrap modal form redirect on validation failed

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-modal

I have Bootstrap Modal which contains form. When validation form is failed redirect to the original form page. The question is how to make that server send me response with errors in my bootstrap modal?

urls.py

```
url(r'^add/$', CreateCarView.as_view(), name='add_auto'),
```

views.py

```
class CreateCarView(CreateView):
model = Car
template_name = 'automobiles/automobiles_add.html'
fields = '__all__'

def get_success_url(self):
    messages.success(self.request, 'Авто успішно додано')
    return reverse('home')

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.POST.get('cancel_button'):
        messages.info(self.request, 'Додавання відмінено')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('home'))
    else:
        return super(CreateCarView, self).post(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

base.html

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
                data-remote="{% url 'add_auto' %}">
            Open Modal
        </button>
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

automobiles_add.html

```
<form id="add_item" class="form" role="form" action="{% url 'add_auto' %}" method="post">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Додати авто</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Додати тачку" name="add_button">
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Відмінити" name="cancel_button">
</div>
```

Comment: I suggest using ajax for this form submit. But that will require more code. Or you could insert django form errors in the modal as the docs says, and redirecting with some url param which will be fetched from JS to open the modal on page load.

Answer (score 2):

this may look like a hack but you could manually launch the modal if there are errors on the form, something like

```
<form id="add_item" class="form" role="form" action="{% url 'add_auto' %}" method="post">
<div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h4 class="modal-title">Додати авто</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="Додати тачку" name="add_button">
    <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Відмінити" name="cancel_button">
</div>

{% if form.errors %}
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#myModal').modal({show: true});
    });
    </script>
{% endif %}
```

or something like that.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

when you are submitting, normal form submitting is happening, instead you can post using ajax, this is an example ajax code.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#add_item', function() { 
    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: this.action,
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        context: this,
        success: function(data, status) {
            location.reload();
        },
        error: function (request, type, errorThrown) {
            $('#add_item').html(request.responseText);
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```